# Problem with simple regex

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have the following regular expression in a validation rule:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9',!;?~>+&\"\-@#%*.\s]{1,1000}$
```

However, I can enter `======` which I believe should not be allowed.

My thoughts is that somehow the `-` could cause trouble if not properly escaped or something but this is way over my head.

Comment: Eton, ask a question; what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to escape the `*` and the `.` as well? I'm not a regex expert, but I know those are special characters.

Comment: In firebug, this returns false. Are you sure it's the regex and not some glue code you have elsewhere? `/^[a-zA-Z0-9',!;?~>+&\"\-@#%*.\s]{1,1000}$/.test("======")`

Comment: Yeah, now that I test this, I'm getting `false` as well.  Can you show your actual code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you've shown us with the `-` escaped does not accept `===`.
But if `-` is not escaped, `===` will be accepted. See [**this**](http://www.rubular.com/r/zCi8wNanQg).

A `-` inside a regex is special and is used as range operator if it's not escaped and is surrounded by characters which participate as min and max in the range:

`[a-z]` matches any lowercase character.

`[-az]` matches either a `-` or `a` or `z`.

`[az-]` matches either a `-` or `a` or `z`.

`[a\-z]` matches either a `-` or `a` or `z`.

`[a-c-d-f]` matches `a` or `b` or `c` or `-` or `d` or `e` or `f`. The first and last `-` act as range operator but the one in the middle is treated literally.

In your case the `=` comes in the range `"-@` and hence gets matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
.
```

matches on everything. You want

```
\.
```

Comment: Sure? It's inside these brackets: `[]`

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `-` will be interpreted as a range indicator.  You need to put it either first or last within the `[]` brackets if you want to match a literal `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works fine for me but if I remove the escaping of `-` it matches `=`. I'm sure you are doing that.